# Django equivalent(s) of Rails controller inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-views

A common pattern that I used with Rails was controller inheritance. I would put various pieces of shared functionality into a base controller, either `ApplicationController` or some more domain-/concern-specific controller, and then inherit from this base controller to create individual controllers.

Here are some things that I have done or have seen various Rails apps do with controller inheritance.

- Place for certain kinds of shared code to live.
- Apply shared pre-/post-filters to the request. Potentially, modify the incoming request, modify the outgoing response, or alter the flow of the request, using e.g. `before_filter`. Common use-cases include authentication/authorization, request validation, and app state pre-condition checking.
- Provide shared rendering context for state-/session-dependent parts of  parts of shared base template, e.g. a filter sets some instance variables which the base template then uses. For example, a site has a shared header which displays certain domain-specific details of the current user and session.

Here are some things that I have done or seen various Django apps do. They don't quite line up with the above, and there's some gaps that I'm not sure how to replicate in a clean way.

- I've seen Django apps tend to make more use of regular Python functions to encapsulate many kinds of code re-use, making use of python modules for code organization.
- In the case of function-based Django views, one possible way to implement pre-/post-filters is to use a decorator which conditionally calls the underlying view. Is there a way to avoid the need to explicitly attach decorators to each view?
- I don't really know a good, general way to deal with the base template context. In some cases, if the shared component is relatively localized, I can use a custom template rendered as a custom template tag using `register.inclusion_tag` or other similar mechanism, but this does not feel like a good option if the context-dependent content cannot easily be factored out into a single component. In other cases, if the additional context is used everywhere, the desired state can be injected into the request with a middleware, but this does not feel like a good option if this should be localized to e.g. a certain subset of routes. But neither of those feels as general as Rails controller inheritance, and in particular, I do not know a good solution for supplying additional template rendering context vars to the base template analogously to instance variables on a base controller.

What would be the recommended/idiomatic ways to accomplish the above in Django? Granted, Rails and Django have some philosophical and architectural differences, so "equivalent of X" is not going to be an absolute one-to-one. Still, I'm hoping for some insight on how to do these commonly-desired use-cases.

Thanks for reading this wall of text and thanks in advance for your insights!

P.S., a related question and answer which touches on some of these points:
[Django equivalent to Rails application_controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026577/django-equivalent-to-rails-application-controller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the equivalent django methods/functions:

> Place for certain kinds of shared code to live.

If its in the views, use Class Based Views; since these are just like normal classes, you can inherit from them and extend them (called "mixins" - because you mix functionality that you need).

Refer: [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/)

> Apply shared pre-/post-filters to the request. Potentially, modify the
>   incoming request, modify the outgoing response, or alter the flow of
>   the request, using e.g. before_filter. Common use-cases include
>   authentication/authorization, request validation, and app state
>   pre-condition checking.

There are many ways to do this; depending on how specific or generic you want the implementation:

1. Decorators (for function and class based views)
2. Class inheritance (for class based views)
3. Wrapper functions at the URL level (similar to decorators, but extrapolated to the URL mapper).
4. Middleware (even higher level abstraction).

> Provide shared rendering context for state-/session-dependent parts of
>   parts of shared base template, e.g. a filter sets some instance
>   variables which the base template then uses. For example, a site has a
>   shared header which displays certain domain-specific details of the
>   current user and session.

In django, such template-wide functionality is provided by [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/); which take the request and return a dictionary (a mapping) which is then available across all templates.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! In particular, thank you for pointing out template context processors. I believe they fill in the missing gap in my use-case that I previously had.